# ReactJS two same ajax calls with different parameter

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, reactjs

two same ajax calls with different parameter, the second one is overwriting first one, causing result to be different, each time I refresh it. setState in first one I have set tests: [], testsHistories: [] in first ajax, second one set state for tests. Why is having second ajax call affect first one?

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
     this.onFormSubmit = this.onFormSubmit.bind(this);
     this.state = { tests: [],
       testsHistories: [], testInfo: []}; 

   $.ajax({
      url: "http://localhost:xxxx/api/Testing?sorton=datecompleted&order=asc",
      success: (data) => {
         console.log("success");
         this.setState({tests: data, testsHistories: data}
                      );
        },
        error: function(xhr,status,err){
          console.log('error');
        }
    });

    $.ajax({
       url: "http://localhost:xxxx/api/Testing?"+ admissionId,
     // url: "http://localhost:xxxx/api/Testing?admissionId=5",
      success: (data) => {
         console.log("success");
         this.setState({testInfo: data});
        },
        error: function(xhr,status,err){
          console.log('error');
        }
    });
  }
```

Comment: Is `setState` using an assignment? If so, you will only be able to have a result from one query. To "accumulate" the results as properties on you single state object, use [Object#assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)

Comment: @DarrenSweeney Why would you set the state manually and forego React's automatic handling of state updates?

Comment: @sbking you're right, I read it wrong, I thought he was setting same state object from both

Answer (score 0):

Your code should also work, `setState` don't affect the other `state` values.

**Suggestions and another way of writing the same code:**

Don't do the api call's and `setState` inside `constructor`, `constructor` is used to initialise the variables not to update.

Use `componentDidMount` lifecycle method and do the api calls inside that.

As per [DOC](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount):

> componentDidMount() is invoked immediately after a component is
>   mounted. Initialization that requires DOM nodes should go here. If you
>   need to load data from a remote endpoint, this is a good place to
>   instantiate the network request. Setting state in this method will
>   trigger a re-rendering.

Write it like this:

```
class App extends Component {
    constructor(props){
      super(props);
      this.onFormSubmit = this.onFormSubmit.bind(this);
      this.state = { 
          tests: [],
          testsHistories: [], 
          testInfo: []
      };
    } 

    componentDidMount(){
        $.ajax({
            url: "http://localhost:xxxx/api/Testing?sorton=datecompleted&order=asc",
            success: (data) => {
              this.setState({tests: data, testsHistories: data});
            },
            error: function(xhr,status,err){
              console.log('error');
            }
        });

        $.ajax({
            url: "http://localhost:xxxx/api/Testing?"+ admissionId,
            success: (data) => {
               this.setState({testInfo: data});
            },
            error: function(xhr,status,err){
              console.log('error');
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think this is an answer to OP question, however the correct style of writing for sure

Comment: correct, don't know why he faced that issue. Updated the answer thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

As Mayank Shukla pointed out, AJAX calls typically are called during lifecycle methods. Read more at https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html.

As for why the second AJAX call is affecting the first, if they are affecting independent pieces of state (it appears so), they shouldn't affect each other because state updates should be merged. However, if either call affects each other, I would suggest using callback or promises to ensure that the order of state updates is consistent.